# how can i detect/prevent non linear movement

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see below, the "robotic arm" first goes "cartesian" correctly, but then it cannot follow "cartesian".
i want to use cartesian path, If the cartesian path cannot be solved i want to detect

Please check out the gif iamge below. 
I want the robot arm to go linear 
If the robot arm goes out of linear path, I must stop. 
i use OMPL->RRTstar ,track_ik

[image: image description]

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388569/how-can-i-detect/prevent-non-linear-movement/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-13**:
I do not understand what question you are asking. What do you mean by "non cartesian path"? What about the arm motion do you think is wrong? Also tell us which planner you are using.

Please add this information to your text using the "edit" button at the end of the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, none of the cartesian planners guarantee that the arm links or joints move thru the minimum possible distance. You will have to write your own planner if you need that. Note that some planners can be configured to allow searching more of the state space, but that still does not guarantee you get the "best" solution.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1